# Vagrant plugins fail with "uninitialized constant Rails"

Tags: vagrant

I downloaded and installed Vagrant 2.0.2 on my Mac, successfully provisioned a new virtual machine, however I am not able to share it via `vagrant share`, due to the following error:

> Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:
>
> The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
>   shown below.
>
> uninitialized constant Rails

I tried installing Ruby on Rails, thought that vagrant might need it, still get the same error.

I tried with another plugin, the login one, and got the same error message, so it seems that the problem is related to the plugins.

Here's the list of plugins I currently have installed:

```
$ vagrant plugin list
login (0.1.1)
  - Version Constraint: > 0
share (1.0.1)
  - Version Constraint: > 0

$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 2.0.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue after upgrading, specifically as a result of the *share* plugin.

- `vagrant login` is part of Vagrant core as of [1.7.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#170-december-9-2014) so you shouldn't need it installed as a plugin.
- `vagrant share` was silently removed in 2.0.2 (see https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9485) but it can still be installed manually as *vagrant-share*.

The following commands should fix your issue:

```
vagrant plugin uninstall login
vagrant plugin uninstall share
vagrant plugin install vagrant-share
```

Also note that per docs Vagrant Share via Atlas has been deprecated and it now requires ngrok.

- https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrant-cloud/vagrant-cloud-migration.html#vagrant-share
- https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/